# No puedo realizar una transaccion en la base de datos

Tags: sql-server, jsf

buenas tardes lo que pasa es que mi persistence.xml lo tengo configurado con JTA y al tratar de insertar un dato en la base de datos me genera el siguiente error.

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Exception Description: Cannot use an EntityTransaction while using JTA.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando se utiliza `JTA` no se puede utilizar la forma tradicional de acceder el `EntityManager`, i.e.:

```
EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persistence_unit);
```

o

```
@PersistenceUnit(unitName="persistence_unit")
private EntityManagerFactory factory;

EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
EntityTransaction entityTransaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
```

Lo anterior sólo funciona si se tiene en el `persistence.xml` el

```
transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL";
```

Cuando se utiliza JTA, se está especificando que el contenedor es quien va a proveer el `EntityManager`por lo que se debe utilizar lo siguiente:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="persistence_unit")
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

Y el contenedor es quien se encarga de inyectarlo.

Si quieres solucionar tu error, y no se necesitan multiples contextos, pues simplemente hay que cambiar el `persistence.xml`

de

```
transaction-type="JTA"
```

a

```
transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"
```

[Más info..](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqw.html#bnbqy)